# SSRS Report to show hide a message based on the browser the report is loading in

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anyone know if I will be able to show/hide a message on ssrs report based on the browser the user is using to view the report.

Basically I have got into a difficult situation where I have built a report which was needed, however for some reason it does not load in Internet Explorer. All the graphs get jumbled up when IE is used to view the report. But the report is good on Google Chrome.

So I want to display a text which checks if the browser is Chrome, if No - displays a text message that the report needs to be loaded in Chrome. However when it is loading in Chrome the text box is hidden using the show/hide property for the text box.

It is sloppy now but that's all the time I am left with to invest on this report for the team. please can someone help.

Comment: [Why is can someone help me not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Can't you just set the report to export to .pdf for IE and have it load up that way?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steve. it could be done, but that text box with its show hide property based on the browser it is loading the report in has been agreed by the management and its just a huge task in all to present another situation to everyone and get signed off

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link:[SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/#comments)